# Measuring time for dedups (Dedup.treeSetDedup(array)), seems to always return 0

Tags: java, algorithm, measurement

I'm trying to measure the time it takes to "Dedup" a random set of returned words. If I set maxWords to 1000, it will measure the time it takes to dedup a set of 10 words and increment it by 10 for each iteration until it reaches a 1000 words. The time seems to always be 0, even at 1000 words. I've tried with all the default types of dedups (basicDedup, arrayListDedup, etc...).

[image: treeSetDedup.csv]

```
/*....*/

String[] samples; 
Utils.Sampler sampler = new Utils.Sampler(readFile); //sampler with words to read
Utils.Stopwatch timer = new Utils.Stopwatch(); //Used to measure time
Utils.Output out = new Utils.Output(dedupType + ".csv"); //Makes file with the measurement

for (int i = 10; i <= maxWords; i += 10) {
    int size = i; //Words to read for the iteration
    samples = sampler.get(size); //Array containing the words for the iteration

    long time = 0;
    timer.start();
    Dedup.treeSetDedup(samples);
    time = timer.elapsedTime();

    out.addMeasurement(size, time);

}


/*....*/

public static class Stopwatch {
   private final ThreadMXBean timer;
   private long start;

   public Stopwatch(){
       timer = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
       start();
   }

   /**
    * Start the timer
    */
   public void start(){start = timer.getCurrentThreadCpuTime();}

   /** 
    * Returns the time in nanoseconds since the last call <tt>start()</tt>.
    */
   public long elapsedTime() {
       long now = timer.getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
       return now-start;
   }

   /**
    * Runs the runnable object <tt>r</tt>, and returns the elapsed time
    * measured in nanoseconds.
    */
   public static long elapsedTime(Runnable runnable){
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        runnable.run();
        long stop = System.nanoTime();
        return stop-start;
   }

   /**
    * Calls the given function with the given argument, 
    * and returns the elapsed time measured in nanoseconds.
    */
   public static <T,R> long elapsedTime(Function<T,R> fu, T args){return elapsedTime(() -> fu.apply(args));}

}
```

Comment: Which "Stopwatch" impl are you using? Which Dedup are you using?  If you think it might be a measurement error, replace  `Dedup.treeSetDedup(samples);` with `Thread.sleep(500);` and see if that shows as non-zero.

Comment: The Dedup class was given to me by a teacher. I'm pretty sure it's fine as the words don't seem to be repeating. I can't use Thread.sleep() as it will throw an InterruptedExeption. I will include the StopWatch class in the post.

Comment: So I included:
     try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } Between start and stop, and this still gives me 0..

Comment: Read the javadocs for `ThreadMXBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime`.  I'm pretty sure that's not what you're after. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html#getCurrentThreadCpuTime()